# wxWidgets Blurry Screen and text

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, blurry

I wrote a simple wxWidgets program on CLion. Here, the window which displays is always a little blurred, on the pre-installed sample projects however it works just fine, but running them from CLion does not work as well.

I tried already adding `<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>`, `<string>NSApplication</string>` and `<key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>` to Info.plist, reloading the project as well as CMake cache, but nothing worked so far.
There are no compiler errors or warnings when building the projects.
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

- WxWidgets version: 3.1.5
- OS: Mac OS 11.5.2
- Environment variable in CMake in order to access wxWidgets:

  - `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`
  - `/Users/MyPC/Desktop/wxWidgets-3.1.5/build-cocoa-debug`

This it how it looks:

[image: This it how it loks]

Comment: Have you identified the differences between a wx sample project and your project?

Comment: @Ripi2 I tried using the same CMakeLists.txt and same Info.plist but it did not work. But now I saw, if I run the sample projects CLion or building it from there, it is blurred as well. Only the sampled which could be created through the makefile are without those error.

Comment: @Sintax, how are building wxWIdgets and the and `minimal` sample? You should use the same info.plist as the sample is using...

Comment: @Igor Exactly the same. I tried out using the same CMakeLists.txt, Info.plist as well as  the same compiler settings. Nothing worked

Comment: @Sintax, can y build the minimal sample with provided Makefile?And with prvided `CMkake` thingy?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the information, I have updated the the question accordingly

Comment: @Igor Yes. I can build and run all given samples using makefile and there it works just fine. Only if I build the projects by myself using CLion, the frames and all becomes blurry

Comment: https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?t=46954

Comment: @HansPassant Already tried this, but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: @sintax, what does `CLion` uses? Can you try building with Xcode? Or maybe try building it with makefile provided in a sample.

Comment: All I see is a blank window -- which is why StackOverflow requires your actual code to be copied and pasted into your question as text (indented by 4-spaces, or with the line above and below being `\`\`\`` so it formats as fixed width code with syntax highlight)

Comment: @Igor, indeed. With Xcode the exact same project works just fine. Then it seems to be a problem of Cmake I guess. I'll check that and keep you up to date

Comment: @Sintax, if it is - could you please send an email to wx-users mailing list explaining the problem. I am not sure if the author of `CMake` is reading this. You will need to register if you never done this before...

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should have

```xml
<key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
<string>wxNSApplication</string>
```

(note "wx" in the class name) in your `Info.plist`. If this still doesn't work, make sure that the correct `Info.plist` is actually copied into your application bundle, as from your description it seems that you might not be using the `Info.plist` you think you're using.